# Mobile Compatible view

Tags: mobile

We have a portal, but I am unable to view my login page in mobile view. After login I am able to see the home page in mobile view; how can i change my login page in mobile view? How can I check which css is used in my home page? Are there any predefined css files used for mobile view?

I looked for `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">` but I did not find that in my home page. I am using the correct predefined css file.

Comment: Portal logins are done through the sites login controller. Perhaps this [Help Page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm&language=en_US) will be of some assistance or else point you in the right direction. There's also the [Apex Site Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm) that may be helpful too.

Answer (score 4):

As part of your portal setup, you need to create an associated Force.com Site to serve a custom login page (mobile optimised) and create its associated controller. The only thing after that you need to do is to set it as the ‘Authorization Required Page’ for the Site. That should do it.